# VBA Remove image from filled shape

Tags: excel, vba

I succeeded in filling a shape with an image. However, I loop through several images to create a report for each ranger. So once I created the report, I need to remove that image and fill the shape with another image. I have tried several things but just don't succeed in removing the previous image. Once the first image is loaded, even trying to just loop through and fill the shape again with another does not work. Once the first image is in it remains. I've even tried to load an image that is just a white block. That doesn't work either. Please help me remove this again

[image]

```
Sub rInsertAndResizePicture()
    Dim PicturePath As String
    Dim PictureName As String
    Dim WhiteFill As String
    Dim TargetCell As Range
    Dim Pic As Object
    Dim TargetShape As Shape
    Dim MaxWidth As Double
    Dim MaxHeight As Double
    Dim ShapeWidth As Single
    Dim ShapeHeight As Single
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim imagePath As String, whitePath As String
    Dim rngImage As Picture
    
    
    
    ' Specify the name of the shape
    On Error Resume Next
        Set TargetShape = rRep.Shapes("RangerImageSize")
    On Error GoTo 0

    
    ' Set the path and file name
    PicturePath = rSys.Range("Z2").Value  
    PictureName = rSys.Range("Z3").Value  '"Joel Somseb Torra RR.jpg"
    WhiteFill = "white-600X300.png"
    imagePath = PicturePath & PictureName
    whitePath = PicturePath & WhiteFill
    
    
    ' If the shape exists, add the image to it
    If Not TargetShape Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        TargetShape.Fill.UserPicture whitePath

        '    sRep.Pictures("rngImage").Delete
        ' Check if the shape contains an image
'        If TargetShape.Type = msoAutoShape Then
'        ' Delete the image from the shape
'        TargetShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
'        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

        If Dir(imagePath) <> "" Then
            Set rngImage = rRep.Pictures.Insert(imagePath)
'            Set rngImage = imagePath
            ' Name the image as "rngImage"
            rngImage.Name = "rngImage"
            TargetShape.Fill.UserPicture imagePath
            
        Else
            TargetShape.Fill.UserPicture whitePath
'            TargetShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete the picture, you have to apply the Fill.Solid method.

Something like this

```
    TargetShape.Fill.Solid
```

Comment: That worked well tx

Answer (score 2):

As feedback, here is the code that works

```
    Sub rInsertAndResizePicture()
    Dim PicturePath As String
    Dim PictureName As String
    Dim TargetShape As Shape
    Dim imagePath As String, whitePath As String
    Dim rngImage As Picture
    
    
    
    ' Specify the name of the shape
    On Error Resume Next
        Set TargetShape = rRep.Shapes("RangerImageSize")
    On Error GoTo 0

    
    ' Set the path and file name
    PicturePath = rSys.Range("Z2").Value  '"C:\Users\DELL\Dropbox\000 david wood\_NewAdvAppsProjects\Wadappt\SRT_RangerInfo\"
    PictureName = rSys.Range("Z3").Value  '"Joel Somseb Torra RR.jpg"
    imagePath = PicturePath & PictureName
    
    
    ' If the shape exists, remove the image from it if it exists
    If Not TargetShape Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        TargetShape.Fill.Solid
        TargetShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' White color (you can change the color as needed)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If


    If Dir(imagePath) <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        TargetShape.Fill.UserPicture imagePath
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've inserted a white picture where no picture in DB. Consequently, when the loop reaches "If Not TargetShape Is Nothing" next time, it won't function as intended. I would use a named cell and deleting it if there is no picture for the range. Here's a sample code:

```
 ' You need to name a cell "PictureHere" at the location where you want to insert the picture.
 ' Set the named range where you want to insert the picture
    Set TargetRange = ws.Range("PictureHere")

    ' If the named range "PictureHere" exists, insert the picture
    If Not TargetRange Is Nothing Then
        ' Delete any existing picture in the named range
        For Each Pic In ws.Pictures
            If Not Application.Intersect(TargetRange, Pic.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
                Pic.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Pic

        ' Insert the new picture
        Set Pic = ws.Pictures.Insert(PicturePath)
        With Pic
            ' Position the picture within the named range
            .Top = TargetRange.Top
            .Left = TargetRange.Left
            .Width = TargetRange.Width
            .Height = TargetRange.Height
        End With
    Else
    End If
```